# sql server 2012 maintenance plan error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a simple DB backup plan.  I can create it just fine, but when I run it, this is the error I get.  I did change the user to sa.   Thanks in advance if anyone knows what this is...

> Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [apdev] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Fi..." failed with the following error: "Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Backup\apdev_backup_2017_03_23_135543_9174316.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Command:

> BACKUP DATABASE [apdev] TO  DISK = N''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Backup\apdev_backup_2017_03_23_135543_9174316.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N''apdev_backup_2017_03_23_135543_9174316'', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

Keep in mind that this DID work.  But ever since I ran a robocopy command, it deleted my whole 'Backup' directory.  I replaced the directory by manually adding the 'Backup' folder back to the directory where it was deleted.

Comment: If you read the error it is a disk permissions error (hits: *Access is denied* and *Cannot open backup device*)

Comment: Just a heads up, you should probably consider using Ola's scripts instead of trying to roll your own: [SQL Server Maintenance Solution - SQL Server Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance - Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

Comment: Igor - I edited my question.  Could that be the reason?

Comment: Definitely, there is a user/group that needs access to that directory that is explicitly set during the install of sql server.

Comment: oh crap.  Do I have to re-install sql server again?

Comment: No, you just need to figure out which user it is that needs rights and update the folder permissions

Comment: I added an answer with which user and what rights, that will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But ever since I ran a robocopy command, it deleted my whole 'Backup' directory. I replaced the directory by manually adding the 'Backup' folder back to the directory where it was deleted.

Update the Backup folder's security permissions. Add user `MSSQLSERVER` and allow that user  `Full control` access to that folder. That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the permissions for Backup folder . Add [YourServerName]\Users to allow Full control access. This working well for me.